# Can't see any background image - in IE 7 and IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

For some reason, iE8 and IE7 are not behaving like other browsers, and the relative position element background image, doesn't appear.

Any suggestions please?

The HTML

```
<div id="container1">
    <div class="main-column">
         <h2>Hello tittle 1</h2>

        <div class="text-column">
            <p>I'm on column 1 and I like it</p>
            <p>I'm on column 1 as well</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-column">
         <h2>Hello tittle 2</h2>

        <div class="text-column">
            <p>I'm on column 2 and I like it</p>
            <p>I'm on column 2 as well</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-column">
         <h2>Hello tittle 3</h2>

        <div class="text-column">
            <p>I'm on column 3 and I like it</p>
            <p>I'm on column 3 as well</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notes:

a) Absolute position instead of relative will ruin the all layout.

b) I have a space on my background declaration so it's not a space issue.

Try I:

The same markup, but now with absolute position:

```
#container1 {
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
}

.main-column {
    display: inline-block;
}

.main-column h2 {
    width: 220px;
    height: 235px;
    padding-top: 110px;
    position: absolute; /* <<-- Changed */
    background: url('http://s24.postimg.org/ossqwb7hh/carica_Kairos.png') no-repeat center top;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.text-column {
    width: 220px; /* <<-- Make it equal to the h2 */
    height: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 120px auto 0 auto;
    padding-top: 270px; /* <<-- Adjust */
}

.text-column p {
    padding: 0 50px;
}
```

same issue. IE8 and IE7 not displaying images. :(

Comment: Is the image is of bigger size?

Comment: Actually, this works. And for some really odd reason, the remote absolute path didn't display the image, and when I change the background declaration to a relative path, the images did appear. I rest my case for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're looking to do, but since the h2 is a block item, it might not obey your height/width CSS. I would float or absolute position it.

Comment: As far as I can tell: I can't absolute position this element, otherwise, the all layout will fall apart. I should not float it, because I need it centered, and even if it stays centered, that will perhaps force me to float other elements so that they none looses the flow. I cannot make inline-block, because IE7 will not understand that.

Comment: I want that this code that looks on a certain way on good browsers, behave as well on IE8 and IE7 with a very similar look.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Here is a working workaround, please test it on youtr machine since I'm using IE8 emulator. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YMtfn/)

HTML

```
 <div id="container1">
                <div class="main-column">
                    <div class="h2"><span>Title 1</span><img src="http://s24.postimg.org/ossqwb7hh/carica_Kairos.png" width="230" height="243" /></div>
                    <div class="text-column">
                        <p>I'm on column 1 and I like it</p>
                        <p>I'm on column 1 as well</p>
                    </div>
                </div><br>
                <div class="main-column">
                     <div class="h2"><span>Title 1</span><img src="http://s24.postimg.org/ossqwb7hh/carica_Kairos.png" width="230" height="243" /></div>
                    <div class="text-column">
                        <p>I'm on column 1 and I like it</p>
                        <p>I'm on column 1 as well</p>
                    </div>
                </div><br>
                <div class="main-column">
                     <div class="h2"><span>Title 1</span><img src="http://s24.postimg.org/ossqwb7hh/carica_Kairos.png" width="230" height="243" /></div>
                    <div class="text-column">
                        <p>I'm on column 1 and I like it</p>
                        <p>I'm on column 1 as well</p>
                    </div>                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
#container1 {
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
}

.main-column {
    display: inline-block;
}

.main-column .h2 {
    width: 220px;
    height: 244px;
    padding-top: 110px;
    position: relative;
    /*background: url('http://s24.postimg.org/ossqwb7hh/carica_Kairos.png') no-repeat center top;*/
}
.main-column .h2 span{
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 243px;
    margin-top: -110px;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: large;
}

.main-column .h2  img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -4px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.text-column {
    width: 220px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: -223px auto 0 auto;
    padding-top: 220px;
}

.text-column p {
    padding: 0 50px;
}
```

*OLD answer below*

It seems you are using `<h2>` like a block when its a header element. You should try these tips for now:

1. Explicitly declare `display: block;` on that element.
2. Explicitly declare them all as `position: relative;`
3. Change the `<h2>` tag to a `<div>`

Comment: By all, what elements do you mean? Display block doesn't change nothing. :(

Comment: try them all. Still no images appear.

Comment: try this fiddle, I think it'll work since it is a workaround.

Comment: none of those work. I end up using something totally different. I also end up finding that I can't rely on IE8 and IE7 render on Virtual Box, mainly due to cache issues. Anyway, thanks for your time on this. Gave you +1.